# Why declaring the data type of a variable after its declaration?

Tags: c, types, variable-assignment

For example:

```
volatile int a;
int b = 5;

a = (int)(5*b);
```

Why should i do that? The variable `a` already has its data type.

I am reviewing a code not written by me and i found that. Couldn't understand why, didn't find anythin on the internet.

Comment: That is a cast: not a declaration.  Don't really need it.  Someone is probably trying to avoid warnings in case b is changed to a different type.  Personal preference is not to cast unless you really need to - let the compiler warn you about it before you do anything about it - that way, at least you know

Comment: Okay you were clear, so it's not necessary. I found it really confusing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`a = (int)(5*b);` is type casting the result of the expression `(5*b)` into integer and assigning it into variable `a`. It is not a re-declaration of variable `a`.

For more details regarding type casting in C kindly refer the following tutorial

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Comment: okay but i am still not understanding why do i need to say `a = (int)(5*b);`

Comment: In your example it is unnecessary since both variable `a` and `b` has same data type of int. A more practice example is 

`int sum = 17, count = 5;`
`double mean;`
`mean = (double) sum / count;`

here if you don't do typecasting the result will be truncated.